# Radare2: How to Create a Custom Scripted Panel?

Tags: debugging, radare2, python, script, visualization

**TLDR: How do I get a panel in radare2 to correctly show the output of a radare2 command piped to an external script?**

**e.g. `afvd | python var_displayer.py`**

- This is my current view. Multiple panels, using radare2's `v` command. Note the `afvd` and RegisterRefs (`drr`) panels.

[image]

- I love RegisterRefs (`drr`) because it shows values at addresses. I love `afvd` because it shows all var values.
- **Problem: `afvd` only shows var values as decimal.**
- Sometimes, it makes more sense to see it as hex.
- Sometimes, it makes more sense to see it as ASCII.
- **I want to create something like `afvdr` that shows var values in different formats + refstr,** like `drr` does for registers.
- I want to replace my current `afvd` panel with this new tool.

What do I have so far?

- I know that if I take a var's value (e.g. `var_8h` = `4287356032`) and run the r2 command `? <expr>`, it will evaluate the expression and show me different representations!

[image]

- I developed a python script, called `var_displayer.py` that will read the output from `avfd` and calculate and neatly display the `hex` and `string` representations the same as the `? <expr>` command would. I run it within r2 using `afvd | python scripts/var_displayer.py`. Here's the output:

[image]

- This is awesome! I don't have the dereference functionality (treat var value as an address and show the value underlying), which would be useful like `drr`, but this is great for me!
- However, a problem occurs when I try to replace the `afvd` panel with `afvd | python scripts/var_displayer.py`.

[image]

- Note how the panel only shows the output of `afvd`, and note how the string generated by my python script is awkwardly appended to the entire radare2 panels output in the bottom left.
- My python script builds the output string in one variable named `output_string` and then outputs this string with a call to `sys.stdout.write(out_string)`. **Unfortunately, radare2 doesn't seem to expect this for a panel's display.**

THANKS FOR READING SO FAR!!!

**My Questions Are:**

1. **Is it possible to configure a radare2 panel to neatly show the output of an external script/program?**
2. **Is there a better way to achieve the evaluate functionality (`? <expr>`) and dereference evaluate functionality (`drr` refstr column) for vars that is native to radare2?**

I'm falling in love with radare2 for it's customizability and elegance and slick CLI feel, but I'm pretty surprised to find custom script --> panel is not working. I feel like there must be a way to achieve this that I haven't figured out yet.